# Why "обо всём" but "перед всем"?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, история-языка

Why is it

> об**о** мне
>
> об**о** всём

but

> перед**о** мной
>
> перед всем

Comment: I am not a native speaker, but as far as I know, о(бо) must be followed by the prepositive case, whereas перед(о) must be followed by the instrumental case. Hence the different forms of the pronouns in your examples.

Comment: @Giorgio, I'm not the author of the question, but I guess it about `-o` ending.

Comment: @shabunc: Ok. Then, I can only try to guess. AFAIK the -o is often inserted after a preposition to avoid a consonant cluster. My guess is that the Russians avoid a cluster of three consonants, at least two of which have a similar articulation. Therefore: -б мн- (б м), -б вс- (б в), -д мн- (д н) are avoided by inserting an -o. On the other hand, -д вс- is acceptable (all three consonants are articulated differently), and no -o is inserted. Again, this is only a guess and I am curious to read a more authoritative answer.

Comment: @Giorgio, I think so as well. I think also, that one can find reduced vowel between `в` and `с` in `всем` and this is the reason for 'перед всем' to be acceptable. However, I'm not devoted enough to dig into the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the answer on Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_316395)

> *Передо* — предлог, употребляется перед формами *мной*, *мною*, а также перед формами творительного падежа существительных, в которых представлены начальные сочетания «ль, л, м, р + согласная».

So **передо** is used instead of *перед* before nouns in instrumental case which start with “**ль, л, м, р + consonant**”.

---

The rules for *о/об/обо* are different.
I think it is incorrect to compare two different prepositions which require different cases.

In general, *-о* is added when it's hard to pronounce the consonant cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if some particular rule applies here, but I think that vowel `о` is inserted before two consecutive sonorants (`лнмр`) in next word so it's easier to pronounce, `мн` is the most frequent one.

That I'm talking about is that `перед мной` is pretty legitimate form (esp. in form `пред мной` for example), however `о` is usually added for ease of prononciation. While there is no need to insert `о` in `обо` since it's already there.

Comment: I'm not asking about why `об` changes to `обо`... I'm asking why `об` does change, but `перед` does NOT change when used with `всё`, yet both change when used with `я`.

Comment: That's *exactly* that I'm talking about.

Comment: What do you mean by "о in обо since it's already there"? `обо` is `об` + `о`, just as `передо` is `перед` + `о`. The two should follow the same rule, that `о` is added before consonant clusters.

Comment: No, `об` is `o` + `б`, while `обо` is `о` + `б` + `о` and is synonym to `о`. Thus `обо мне` is actully equv. to `о мне`. `Об` is used insted of `о` if next word is starts from vowel, e.g. `об этом`.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant to write... The fact remains that `передо` IS `перед` + `о`, the same way as `об` is `о` + `б` + `о`

Comment: So what? Anyway, see Alexey Ivanov's answer, since he explains absolutely the same thing, but is more succesful in it.